# Programmatically terminating PubSubIO.readMessages from Subscription after configured time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am looking to schedule the Dataflow which has PubSubIO.readString from a PubSub topic's subscripton. How can i have the job to be terminating after a configured interval? My usecase is not to keep the job running through the entire day, so looking to schedule to start, and then stop after a configured interval from within the job.

```
Pipeline
    .apply(PubsubIO.readMessages().fromSubscription("some-subscription"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stopping-a-pipeline):

> If you need to stop a running Cloud Dataflow job, you can do so by
>   issuing a command using either the Cloud Dataflow Monitoring Interface
>   or the Cloud Dataflow Command-line Interface.

I would assume that you are not interested in stopping jobs manually via Console, which leaves you with the command line solution. If you intend to schedule your dataflow job to run e.g. daily, then you know at which time you want it to stop too (launch time + "configured interval"). In that case, you could configure a cron job to run the [`gcloud dataflow jobs cancel`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/cancel) at that time every day. For instance, the following script would cancel all active jobs having been launched within the day:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcloud dataflow jobs list --status=active --created-after=-1d \
| awk '{print $1;}' | tail -n +2 \
| while read -r JOB_ID; do gcloud dataflow jobs cancel $JOB_ID; done
```

Another solution would be to invoke the `gcloud` command within your java code, using [`Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322785/9251751). You can schedule this to run after a specific interval using `java.util.Timer().schedule()` as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258080/9251751). This way you can ensure your job is going to stop after the provided time interval regardless of when you launched it.

**UPDATE**

@RoshanFernando correctly noted in comments that there's actually an [SDK method](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html#cancel--) to cancel a pipeline.

Comment: Can you share me some examples of invoking gcloud command within the java code?

Comment: I also found options to call cancel/drain programmatically using their built-in Pipeline job apis. Thanks again.