# Java apis to query RPM package information for file

Tags: java, rpm

In Linux, RPM package information for a file can be determined using the 'rpm -qf' option. Is anyone aware of a JAVA library which supports these kind of operations?

E.g.:

```
/bin # rpm -qf grep
grep-2.7-5.7.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of any library that provides an easy API to check RPM package info.  You can, however, use Java to execute shell commands and interpret their results.

Some more info:

- [Executing shell commands from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062305/executing-shell-commands-from-java)
- [Want to invoke a linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410741/want-to-invoke-a-linux-shell-command-from-java)

Answer (score 2):

There is [Redline RPM](http://redline-rpm.org/index.html), which has a [Scanner](http://redline-rpm.org/apidocs/org/redline_rpm/Scanner.html) that might do what you want. I've used it to package RPMs via Ant/Maven, but never to read them.

Comment: I had already checked Scanner. As per its API, it checks the contents of a given RPM file. Not the reverse.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question quite right. I think @Lev is right, then -- you'll probably have to spawn a process. A pure Java solution for wouldn't make too much sense given how specific to a sub-family of OS this is.